# difference between cstdint and tr1/cstdint

Tags: c++, c++11, tr1

What is the difference between `<cstdint>` and `<tr1/cstdint>`? (apart from that one puts things in namespace `std::` and the other in `std::tr1::`)

Since this stuff isn't standard yet I guess it's compiler specific so I'm talking about gcc. To compile with the non-tr1 one I must compile with `-std=c++0x`, but there is no such restriction when using tr1.

Is the answer perhaps that there is none but you can't go around adding things to `std::` unless there, well, standard. So until c++0x is standardised an error must be issued using `<cstdint>` but you dont need to worry when adding to the `tr1::` namespace, which makes no claim to things in it being standard? Or is there more to this?

Thanks.

p.s - If you read "std" as standard, as I do, I do apologise for the overuse of the word in this Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least as far as I know, there was no intent to change `<cstdint>` between TR1 and C++0x. There's no requirement for `#include`ing `<cstdint>` to result in an error though -- officially, it's nothing more or less than undefined behavior. An implementation is allowed to specify exact behavior, and in this case it does.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, didn't mean to imply that the compiler was obliged to error when adding to `std::`, but that is sort of what i said isn't it so thankyou for clearing up the ambiguity. Do you mean that adding to `std::` causes undefined behaviour though? I didn't realise that, just thought it was very bad form. good to know. Also, reading between the lines, can I safely assume that TR1 headers will not change now, while the C++0x ones obviously can (and most probably will).

Comment: The TR1 headers are what they are, and won't change. At this point, I'd be pretty surprised to see any significant changes in the C++0x headers either though -- they've already produced the "final committee draft" and closed the official comment period for C++0x, so at this point it's mostly a matter of answering all official comments, and doing final cleanup on the wording, but for the most part the *intent* of the document should stay the same -- it's just a matter of making sure it actually says what's intended.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've got it.  On my system, they're very similar, but with different macro logic.  For instance, `/usr/include/c++/4.4/tr1/cstdint` has:

```
#  define _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_TR1 namespace tr1 {
#  define _GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_TR1 }
#  define _GLIBCXX_TR1 tr1::
```

but /`usr/include/c++/4.4/cstdint` has:

```
#  define _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_TR1
#  define _GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_TR1
#  define _GLIBCXX_TR1
```

So if it's being included as `<cstdint>` the TR1 namespace is simply defined into oblivion.

Comment: great thanks, much as i expected then. good to have it confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

`<tr1/cstdint>` is defined, as name suggests, in [TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#C_compatibility), while `<cstdint>` is defined in [c++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x).

From gcc manual, `-std=c++0x` is needed to enable experimental features that are likely to be included in C++0x. However, `<tr1/cstdint>` is defined in [TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#C_compatibility), not [c++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x), so `-std=c++0x` is no needed.

The following is gcc manual for `-std=c++0x` for your reference.

> The working draft of the upcoming ISO C++0x standard. This
>      option enables experimental features that are likely to be
>      included in C++0x. The working draft is constantly changing,
>      and any feature that is enabled by this flag may be removed
>      from future versions of GCC if it is not part of the C++0x
>      standard.